# Bug in LeapYearQ?

Tags: date-and-time

```
{#, LeapYearQ[DateObject @ {#, 1, 1}]} & /@ Range[-1000, 3000, 100]
```

I'm surprised to find 0, 400, 800, 1200 with a True. I'm not aware that the leap year rule of the Gregorian calendar was applied retroactively (and that couldn't work, you can't just "redate" a date that was centuries ago, which would mean everything subsequently would have to get re-shifted ...). And then why does it stop at 0? Because the Gregorian calendar's predecessor was the Julian calendar, and Caesar died in -33 (so there were no leap years before Caesar)? If that's the reason, then there is the notion of "there was none before ...". But then why not for the Gregorian calendar? If that's not the reason, then why stop at 0, why are -100, -200 ,-300, -500, etc. not leap years?

**Update / Edit:**
Thanks ciao for your helpful comment. Indeed, I see that with:

```
{#,LeapYearQ[DateObject @ {#, 1, 1}]}& /@ Range[-1000, 2000] // Cases[{_, True}]
```

However, should be documented. Is not documented in the help browser page, nor any reference to ISO 8601:2004 (clause 4.3.2.1 The Gregorian calendar).

Details and Options would be a great place to put that information.

Comment: "I'm not aware that the leap year rule of the Gregorian calendar was applied retroactively...". MMA uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar here.